# Best way to define obj constructor in namespace javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

**I want to keep obj consructors in some namespace with having no problems on debug.**

Right now I have code like this:

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.myConstructor = function(){};
// ----------- debug in console
(new namespace.myConstructor()); // -> namespace.myConstructor {}
(new namespace.myConstructor()).constructor; // -> function (){}
```

I dont like that constructor is anonymous.
So I could do it in other  ways:

(better, but ugly)

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.myConstructor = (function(){
  function myConstructor(){};
  return myConstructor;
})();
// ----------- debug in console
(new namespace.myConstructor()); // -> myConstructor {}
(new namespace.myConstructor()).constructor; // -> function myConstructor(){}
```

or (the most beautful and shortest way)

```
namespace.myConstructor = function myConstructor(){};
// ----------- debug in console
(new namespace.myConstructor()); // -> myConstructor {}
(new namespace.myConstructor()).constructor; // -> function myConstructor(){}
```

But I read [here](http://kiro.me/blog/nfe_dilemma.html), that there are some problems with NFE (Named Function Expression).

Which way is better? Which way is good practice?

Comment: @Yve I've removed extra questions. Is it Ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IE8 problems are exaggerated and don't really matter at all in practice because the functions will be declared in short-lived IIFEs that cannot reference the function by name anyway because then your code will not work in a real browser.

Remember to capitalize constructor names.

```
(function(){
    var namespace = {
        MyConstructor: function MyConstructor() {

        },

        ...
    }
})();
```